# Bcrypt node.js returns false on compare

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, passport.js

i got a problem with bcrypt on node.js -> the bcrypt compare method returns false while comparing the passwords from a mongoDB and a user entry. I have no idea why and i tried to debug it since 3 days but i really need some extern help...

UserShema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
name: {
type: String,
required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}

});
```

hash and salt:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
var user = this;
if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
} else {
    return next();
}
});
```

and finally: the compare method:

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (passw, cb) {
bcrypt.compare(passw, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) {
        return cb(err);
    }
    cb(null, isMatch);
});
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Thx alot!

Comment: FWIW you don't need to explicitly generate a salt, you can just pass the number of rounds as the second argument instead and it will do it for you: `bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) { ... })`

Comment: Are you passing the arguments in the right order (is `passw` the plaintext password and `this.password` the hashed version)? Did you verify `this.password` (to make sure it's a properly hashed value) and that `passw` is indeed a plain string containing the exact password?

Comment: i tried it without a salt-> same result. now i think that this.password is undefined but i have no clue why -_-